Rotational Mechanics
If a body(rigid) is rolling without slipping on a plank then the relative velocity of the body wrt to plank = $v_{bp}$ = 0. Now suppose plank velocity = $v_p$ =0, then v(of centre of mass of body)= $v_{cm}=\omega r$.
Also every particle on the body has two velocities viz., velocity of the centre of mass and $v=\omega r$, so the point of contact velocity = 0 ,so the body is instantaneously at rest(not moving linearly), now for every dt($\Delta$t ->0) time interval there will be unique(or maybe not?) points which act as point of contact. So evey point of contact's velocity = 0, then how does the body move forward if for every dt time interval velocity of point of contact will be 0?

You've acknowledged (beginning of you second paragraph) that the body's centre of mass is moving. You can't logically then say (third line of your second paragraph) that the body is instantaneously at rest. It's only the (temporary) point of contact with the ground that is at rest.

In my mind I know it doesn't happen...so thats why I put quite a contradiciting sentence, my bad for framing the question wrongly

Let's suppose you have a triangle rolling, instead of a wheel.
I hope this clearly shows how it can roll forward with a point staying static on the ground. Now take the wheel as a many sided polygon with side length $dr$ ...

So this is how it works.

really thanks for the visual clarity!Wonder why I didn't think like this

The point of contact is not a moving material point. If we follow a given point in the circle, its horizontal velocity changes all the time, reaching a maximum at the top and zero when it is in contact with the soil.
In a frame of reference moving with the wheel, the horizontal velocity of a point in the periphery is $$v_h' = |v|sin(\theta) = \omega rsin(\omega t)$$ For the ground frame, we have to add the velocity of the wheel: $$v_h = \omega r + \omega rsin(\omega t) = \omega r (1 + sin(\omega t))$$ This point has zero velocity only when $t$ is such that $sin(\omega t) = -1$ (when it touches the soil).

Deleting my previous comment cuz just realised I actually didn't understand what you meant to say.
How is $v'_h = |v|sin(\theta)$ , didn't really get you there. My doubt mainly lies which angle is $\theta$ if possible a diagram is appreciated, nonetheless an explanation enough is ok too

@dezzray If we set the origin at the centre of the wheel, $\theta$ is the angle that a line to a point of the periphery has with the horizontal. It follows the trigonometric convention, increasing counter-clockwise. The wheel moves to the left accordingly.

ok got it whats $\theta$ is. Thanks for helping out

It moves forward because, with the wording you used, the point of contact is not actually a point.  It's a collection of different points, a different one at each moment in time.  If you want to think about it this way, the current point of contact, at any moment in time, is moving with a velocity of 0 (it's stationary).  However, your choice of which point is "the current point of contact" is moving as the object rotates.
An alternate point of view could be to consider the center of mass as moving, and state that every point in the object has a velocity made up of that $v_{cm}$ plus some relative velocity with respect to that CM.  It's easy to see that ay any moment in time, some of those points have a combined velocity of 0, but that just means the relative velocity (which is cyclical) just happens to equal the opposite of the CM's movement.  It reminds me a lot of the idea that a stopped watch is correct twice each day.
